# EntityFramework string Include() a child property

Tags: entity-framework, syntax

I had an Include method like so

```
public static IQueryable<SlideSet> IncludeParameters(this IDbSet<SlideSet> storage) {
    return storage.Include(ss => ss.Params.Select(x => x.Parameter));
}
```

I am cleaning up my domain model and it no longer makes sense to have `SlideSet.Params` be public.

I know that there is a form of `IDbSet<>.Include()` that takes a string parameter. What is the syntax for using a string while descending into the child property like this?

btw, for those who are wondering, I'm pretty sure

```
return storage.Include(ss => ss.Params.Select(x => x.Parameter));
```

is identical to

```
return storage.Include(ss => ss.Params.Include(x => x.Parameter));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `.`:

```
return storage.Include("Params.Parameter");
```

Comment: Ok thanks, its kind of a big refactoring and I wanted to make sure it was possible before forging ahead.

Comment: For completeness sake, [the docs for IQueryable.Inclue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696395(v=vs.103).aspx) mention this, just not the docs for the more specific `IDbset.Include` where I was looking... Ugh.